# ¿Cómo subir un archivo de vídeo via file input y mostrarlo en un elemento <video> angular 2?

Tags: html5, angularjs-2.0, video

Estoy intentando subir un archivo de video en angular 2 por el momento logre subir el archivo pero no logro que se cargue en elemento **video** pero solo se carga el reproductor y no asi el archivo, que estoy haciendo mal.

Input de subida

```
<div class="btn btn-info btn-raised">
    Subir Foto
    <input id="custom-input" type="file" (change)="fileChangeListener($event)" accept="video/*">
</div>
```

contenedor que deberia mostrar el video

```
<video controls>
    <source src="{{ data.video }}" type="{{ data.type }}">
</video>
```

y este es el codigo en Typescript

```
private fileChangeListener($event) {
    let fileList: FileList = $event.target.files;
    this.data = {};
    if (fileList.length > 0) {
        let file: File = fileList[0];
        console.log('video seleccionado', file);
        let myReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
        let that = this;
        myReader.onloadend = (loadEvent: any) => {
            console.log('video', myReader.result);
            this.data.video = myReader.result;
            this.data.type = file.type;
        };
        myReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

podrías intentar con esto:

```
//<video controls> codigo del usuario
//<video controls *ngIf="data.video"> respuesta 
<video controls *ngIf="data.video">
    <source src="{{ data.video }}" type="{{ data.type }}">
</video>
```

Agregando el *ngIf obligas a desplegar el contenido hasta que este, esté disponible, es un detalle que se tiene con el "change detection" funciona de esa manera o metiendo tu codigo dentro de un NgZone.

Comment: Por favor [edit] tu respuesta explicando la diferencia de este código con el código colocado por el usuario "Ricardo D. Quiroga".

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono correctamente, al parecer el componente video se tiene que especificar el source antes de ser renderizado.